# a particular solution for the diffirencial equation: (x+i)y'+y=2xarctanx

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, discrete-mathematics, partial-differential-equations

how to find a particular solution y for the diffirencial equation:
$$(x+i)y'+y=2x\arctan(x)$$
the original equation was: $$(x+i)y'+y=1+2x\arctan(x)$$
I solved for $$(x+i)y'+y=0$$
then $$(x+i)y'+y=1$$
now I'm working on the second term ($2x\arctan(x)$)

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left[(x+i)\cdot y\right]&=2x\cdot\tan^{-1}{(x)}\\
\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left[x^{2}\cdot\tan^{-1}{(x)}-x+\tan^{-1}{(x)}\right]
\end{align}
$$